# Source code of HTML page without Framework

Tags: javascript

Question pretty much sums it up. I don't have access to a framework and I need to get the FULL HTML Source of the current page. Is there some command that is supported by JS natively?

For the record, I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: and what's wrong with that solution ?

Comment: I do not see how what you have isn't good enough.

Comment: It doesn't involve the HTML tags, which I need, because I'm comparing two sources and the first one contains the <HTML> tag. @BigMike

Comment: then change innerHTML with outerHTML

Comment: You'd still miss the doctype and things like that. Fetching the page via AJAX might be what you want?

Comment: @WillemMulder agree, but that can be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @BigMike Sure, all depends on what you want. Value versus cost :-)

Comment: For anybody with the same needs, take a look at `Live.js`. Really nice bit of javascript for automatic updates. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in a one-liner using [*XMLSerializer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer).

```
var generatedSource = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

Which gives *String*

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

<title>javascript - Source code of HTML page without Framework - Stack Overflow</title>
...
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it seems to be cutting out some spaces and carriage returns that were there before?

Comment: @Chris this is a ** _generated_ ** source, not the _original_ source. The browser's parsing of the original source is where those spaces and new lines are removed (or even added).

Comment: And I'm guessing this is as close as I'm gonna get to the original source?

Comment: @Chris the only way to get closer I know of is to re-request the page using ajax.

Comment: Aye, which is what I've done to get the comparison page! The page changes an awful lot, dynamically, so the local copy was what I was going to use. Perhaps there's another away around this. I'll mark this as correct, because 99.9% of the time this is what someone will want.

Comment: @RichieHindle wrong, that is just Gecko's _serializeToStream_ method which never made it to [the spec](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#the-xmlserializer-interface).

Comment: @PaulS.: Sorry, you're quite right.  Erroneous comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to get the complete, actual, live page source from the current page. (edit: as it seems, it is possible! See @Paul S. his answer)

But what you could do to load the initial, unaltered HTML, just load the page through AJAX, and then check the page source as it is returned by the server.

```
$.get(document.location.href, function(response) { 
    window.console.log(response);
});
```

This is with jQuery, but you would alternatively use

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        window.console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",document.location.href,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Why would you use AJAX to get the source code of the page you're already on?

Comment: Isn't it overly complicated to get the source of the page the Javascript is actually running on ? Good solution to get the source of another page though !

Comment: @j08691 Beause you'd get the original source code, not the current (possibly altered) source.

Comment: @j08691 and to get the DOCTYPE tags and the like, that you will miss if you just look at the tree under the HTML element.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is to check for changes in the data, so I can reload the webpage automatically, when something in the backend changes. I am using AJAX, exactly in the way you've specified, to get the server's copy of the HTML. Now I need to get the local copy of the HTML to check if there is a difference. The logic being, if there IS a difference, something has changed in the back end and the page should refresh.

Comment: OP said the only tags he wasn't getting that he cared about were `<html>` and `</html>`.

Comment: @Chris I don't see how changes on a front-end page imply changes at the back-end, but if that is the best way for you to do it, why not...

Comment: Because the Page itself is built by an XSL document, that is generated by XML. The XML changes -> the XSL changes -> The HTML changes.

Comment: @Chris Not too sure about your situation, but why not just do something like set a `lastUpdated` timestamp on the server side, poll for it, and refresh if the time is greater than the current time. In any case, you're better off just asking how to solve your actual problem, the solution you chose seems kind of hacky.

Comment: I'm aware this is something of an X-Y situation, but if I started three days ago and I have absolutely no idea how half of this stuff works, so I'm trying to solve it in a way that I am sure will work.