# Javascript get html of current page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get the html of the page with all modifications made by the user (see below)?

For example, if text has been entered into a textarea, or a checkbox has been chosen, that should be reflected in the html as well. My reason for wanting to do this is to take a "screenshot" of the user's page.

The answers below that are a variation of `jQuery('html')`, do not reflect changes made by the user.

Comment: Duplicate of [javascript page source code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1367587/218196). That's [the second question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17450681/218196) about this within an hour.

Comment: @FelixKling How is this a duplicate? The other question simply asks for the html of the page. I want text inputted in textareas, checkboxes selected, etc. to be reflected in the html

Comment: Ah, I missed the `input`-changes part. The phrase *"modifications made by the user"* is a rather ambiguous. DOM modifications are modifications too (which could happen in response to user interaction).

Comment: *related*: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11632238/218196

Comment: Really, an image of the page is what you where after? That has to be the poorest description of a problem in a question I've ever seen ?

Comment: @adeneo I guess `to take a "screenshot" of the user's page` is a bad description?

Comment: Not really, but `"Javascript get html of current page"` surely is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're wanting a screenshot, you should consider a tool such as [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).  Just pulling the HTML isn't going to get you the input fields.

[Another SO thread along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60455/425809).

Other answers will get you the HTML, specifically, but without the inputs' values

```
$('html').html();
```

Comment: Thanks, although html2canvas is pretty heavy, I guess it can't be helped.

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery:

```
var html = $('html')
```

Comment: What more to give than just this?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui : This one line is actually the demo... no ?

Comment: hmmmm... looks complicated. Is there a simpler method?

Comment: @musefan : do I feel sarcasm ? ;-)

Comment: @musefan : Yes, you could reduce the number of characters used for the var :)

Comment: This doesn't work. For example if I have text in a textarea, it is not reflected in the html.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee - no it's not, the value attribute in the markup is not updated when the user types something, the value property is, so if your goal is to get user inputted text from form elements, getting the markup of the entire page is ***not*** the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting upon the other answers. Prior to obtaining the HTML, you could loop though all the input elements and manually set the `value` property, this would then be reflected in the HTML:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    setValueProperties();
    var html = getHtml();
    alert(html);
});

function setValueProperties(){
    $('input').each(function(){
       $(this).attr("value", $(this).val()); 
    });
}

function getHtml(){
    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ4La/)

[And here is an example that supports checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ4La/1/)

NOTE: You may need to refine this function for your exact needs, but hopefully it will get you on track for what you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a field named "field":

```
var field = document.getElementById("field");
fieldvalue= field.value;
```

If you have a checkbox, the operation is literally the same.  Hope this was helpful.